# How to show the first line of `top` non interatively?

Tags: macos, unix, bsd

`top` on Mac shows something like this on the top of the screen.

`Processes: 1104 total, 187 running, 917 sleeping, 2761 threads                                                               19:41:00`

I don't want to run `top` interactively. Is there a way to run `top` noninteractive and just print this top line to the screen? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like your real question is "How can I get the number of processes running on my Linux system, broken down by running or sleeping?", correct?  First thing I'd do is start looking at the `ps` command.

Comment: No. Ps is not what I am looking for, as it prints too detailed info that I have to post-process. This can be very slow when the system is heavily loaded. It must be one command that directly print the summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ top -l1 | head -n1
```

From the man:

> -l samples
>                Use logging mode and display samples samples, even if standard output is a terminal.  0 is treated as infinity.  Rather than redisplaying, output is periodically printed in raw form.  Note that the first sample displayed will have
>                an invalid %CPU displayed for each process, as it is calculated using the delta between samples.

Answer (score 0):

For example, like this:

```
top -b -n 1 |grep "Processes"
```

more information:

```
man top
```

Comment: This works on Linux but not on Mac. I don't find the corresponding options in the Mac's `top`.

Comment: @user1424739 it works on FreeBSD perfectly. I do not have Macos, but I probably can run the "top" from BSD or GNU on it.